# C# how to initialize list with values from different list using lambdas or something else -- need to simplify

Tags: c#, list, enums, simplify, initializer

I have following code, which I would like to simplify.
I need to fill Clinician's property 'Roles' which is a list of RoleModel, with expected roles which are provided as strings => they need to be split by comma and converted to RoleModel objects.
RoleModel is enum of strings.

Enum looks like this:

```
public enum RoleModel
{
    ClinicManager = 1,
    ClinicAssistant = 2
    ...
}
```

Input data from specflow data table can look like this:

```
| Roles                            |
| Clinic Assistant, Clinic Manager |
```

Therefore I'm applying regex to remove the spaces and split it into a list because it needs to be converted to enums because Clinician model has list 'Role' of RoleModel values.

Currently I have it like this:

```
var expectedRolesString = row["Roles"];
var expectedRoles = Regex.Split(expectedRolesString.Replace(" ", ""), @"\s*[,;]\s*").ToList();

List<RoleModel> RoleList = new List<RoleModel>();
foreach (string role in expectedRoles)
{
   RoleList.Add(Enum.Parse<RoleModel>(role));
}

Clinician = new Clinician()
{
   List<RoleModel> Roles = RoleList 
}
```

I would like to imagine to initialize the list directly like this, but don't know how to use lambas or something else to get list of parsed values for all the strings :(
Is there a way to do all those steps when creating list?

```
Clinician = new Clinician()
{
   Roles = new List<RoleModel>()
   {
      Enum.Parse<RoleModel>(Regex.Split(expectedRolesString.Replace(" ", ""), @"\s*[,;]\s*").ToList()[0]),
      Enum.Parse<RoleModel>(Regex.Split(expectedRolesString.Replace(" ", ""), @"\s*[,;]\s*").ToList()[1]),
      ...
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be something like

```
Clinician = new Clinician()
{
   Roles = expectedRolesString.Split(',',';').Select(r => Enum.Parse<RoleModel>(r.Trim())).ToList()
}
```

<strike>or perhaps</strike>

```
Clinician = new Clinician()
{
   Roles = expectedRolesString.Split(new[]{',',';',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Enum.Parse<RoleModel>).ToList()
}
```

..but I'd have liked to see the input data and enum definition to make sure

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it.
I added the enum and example input data for you in the question description.

Comment: Okay your first solution works perfectly! You're a god!
I just changed the Trim() for Replace(), because the input data have whitespace in the middle of a string .)

Comment: Yep, the neatest for that particular data presentation is probably `Roles = expectedRolesString.Replace(" ","").Split(',').Select(Enum.Parse<RoleModel>).ToList()`